# C++ - Member Function Declaration with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2015, member

I'm writing a class for a project using Visual Studio, I added the class through the IDE menus, the class is public, the header file is included in the project headers, the source files are included in the project source files.

Constructor, destructor and private members are already set, when I started to write the first member functions i get this error: ***member function may not be declared outside its class***.

This is my first type writing a class in Visual Studio, I know that Code::Blocks requires some linking code, is this the same case?

*in the header:*

```
#pragma once
class myclass
{
public:
    myclass( /*parameters*/ );
    void foo ( /*parameters*/ ); //HERE
    ~myclass();
private:
    /* my data members */
};
```

*in the source file:*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "myclass.h"

myclass::myclass( /*parameters*/ )
{
    /*constructor code*/
}
void myclass::foo( /*parameters*/ ); //HERE
{
}
myclass::~myclass()
{
    /*destructor code*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon here:

```
void myclass::foo( /*parameters*/ ); //Semicolon HERE
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a declaration of a member function outside the class definition. Visual Studio sees it as a declaration because you put a semicolon ; at the end of the function signature of your method foo, remove it.